# Ignore transient pattern on save hibernate entity

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, spring

How to save hibernate entity and ignore (not correct)transient pattern.

for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`REQUEST`")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="`receiver`",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=20)
public abstract class Request implements UUIDAble{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Transient
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp="^([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}$")
    private String vaucher;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="name",nullable=false)
private RequestName name;

public RequestName getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(RequestName name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getVaucher() {
    return vaucher;
}
public void setVaucher(String vaucher) {
    this.vaucher = vaucher;
}
}
```

and  i want to save it:

```
Request request = new Request();
request.setVaucher("123");
request.setName(RequestName.SYSTEM);
```

Spring generate error:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: validation failed for classes [ru.icb.cpaclick.domain.OperatorCheckRequest] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:705)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:693)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-checkconstraints-orm. By default, Hibernate (the ORM) checks every constraint of the default validation group. So you might put this particular constraint into another group.

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups for explanations on validation groups.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the groups feature of hibernate validator and assign a different [group](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) to the validation constraints specified on the transient field.

If you want those constraints enabled you need to specifically mention the group.  By default when hibernate tries to save the entity it will check all the validations as part of the default group.